# What should one do while waiting for repetition of the Amidah to start?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, shemoneh-esrei, tefillah-betzibbur

What should an individual be doing after finishing his personal Amidah while waiting for the chazzan's repetition to start? Do the same restrictions apply during this period as the period while the chazzan is actually reciting the repetition ([What should you be doing during the repetition of the Amidah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/47383/what-should-you-be-doing-during-the-repetition-of-the-amidah))? Or is it ok to learn/read silently?

Answer (score 3):

[Kitzur Shulchan Aruch Yalkut Yosef 123:10](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01355_part_7.html#HtmpReportNum0042_L2) permits (and in fact encourages) one to learn silently while waiting for the start of *chazarat hashatz*, but notes that it is preferable not to vocalize the words one is reading.

Once the repetition starts one may not learn silently, rather he should listen to the *chazzan* and respond to his *berachot*.